# Structure for a Hadoop Job over a graph

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, graph

I have an algorithm that have to perform a lot of computations over a graph that can be parallelized and I though I could use Hadoop to assing this computations to the mappers and then resume the results on the reducers, but I'm struggling and beginning to think that maybe I'm using Hadoop for something I shouldn't be using Hadoop (you know, when you have a hammer everything looks like a nail).

You can take a look at a ruby version of the algorithm at https://gist.github.com/brenes/79d980708aae463079b8 but, in sort, it goes like this:

- We have a graph.
- We get a configuration (a list of nodes and edges) that would help us control the whole graph.
- We get rid of one (random) of the nodes of this configuration and get a series of alternative configurations. Then we get one of those configurations (random) as the chosen one.
- For each node, we count how many chosen configurations it's in.

The third step has to be repeated a lot of times (proportional to the number of nodes in the graph), so I though it would be a perfect fit for a Map step. Then, the counting task would be a Reducer step (in fact, the LongSumReducer class fits perfectly).

The problem comes with the two first steps. I thought I could create the graph and get the configuration on a custom InputFormat class, so my custom Reader could just send a random node to each mapper.

This way, the input is not really based on files that are shared over the HDFS, since reading the graph (which would my input file) is performed only by the main node and the mappers would receive everything.

Problem comes when the JobSubmitter tries to write Splits, since they are not really file splits and I get some errors because (I think) it tries to create splitFiles that makes no sense to my structure.

Just to check that I could create the graph, etc, I created a simplified version of the algorim that does:

- We have a graph. (InputFormat and Reader)
- We get each edge of the graph. (Mapper)
- For each node, we count how many edges it has (Reducer)

You can take a look at this simplified version at https://github.com/wild-fire/controllability-samping-algorithm/tree/stack-overflow-30151672

The problem is, when I run the job (with two parameters, the path to the graph file and the path to the output folder) I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.writeNewSplits(JobSplitWriter.java:132)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.createSplitFiles(JobSplitWriter.java:79)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:603)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
  at jobs.SamplingAlgorithm.main(SamplingAlgorithm.java:29)
```

I've been searching about non-file input splits, but only thing I found are tutorials explaining file input splits so I'm starting to wonder, can I do this with Hadoop? Or am I trying to screw with a hammer?

Thanks!

EDIT: As I keep working on it I created (and linked) a tag so you can see the code the moment I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't have a proper way to do it I've found a workaround.

My solution was to move the first steps outside of the Hadoop flow and execute them on my Job class before the Hadoop Job started.

The flow would be:

- Parse the graph.
- Get the first configuration.
- Persist this configuration on a file.
- Get a random list of nodes and persist them into another file.
- Feed this file to a regular Hadoop Job.

Each mapper then receives a line of the temporary random nodes file (a random node) and parses the graph file and configuration files so it performs the required operations.

You can take a look at the last version of the code: https://github.com/wild-fire/controllability-samping-algorithm/tree/master and specially to the Job class: https://github.com/wild-fire/controllability-samping-algorithm/blob/master/src/jobs/SamplingAlgorithm.java.

Since I don't have experience in Hadoop I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it or just a nasty workaround, but I think this answer could hel others with the same problem.